# Using a certificate from Azure Keyvault as a kubernetes secret

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-keyvault, kubernetes-secrets

I've a certificate (pfx) in my Azure KeyVault - I use that certificate as a secret (deployed via Azure DevOps using Helm). The problem I've encountered is that the certificate is somehow incorrectly read from KeyVault (I use Variable Group) - the result is that when my application starts, I get an exception that looks like:

```
error:23076071:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_parse:mac verify failure
```

However, when I manually create a secret (by using powershell to read certificate content as base64) everything works correctly. 
What am I doing incorrectly ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Azure Pipelines variable group integration supports mapping only secrets from the Azure key vault. Cryptographic keys and certificates are not supported. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#secrets-management-notes).

As workaround, you can use [Azure Key Vault task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) in your azure devops pipeline.

> Use this task to download secrets such as authentication keys, storage account keys, data encryption keys, .PFX files, and passwords from an Azure Key Vault instance.
>
> If the value fetched from the vault is a certificate (for example, a PFX file), the task variable will contain the contents of the PFX in string format.

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 
    keyVaultName: 
    secretsFilter: '*'
```

Before using this task. You should ensure the service principal you used in the Azure service connection has at least Get and List permissions on the vault.

This tutorial [Using secrets from Azure Key Vault in a pipeline](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurekeyvault/) might also be helpful.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I was actually able to fetch the certificate via a variable group, the only problem I've is that the content seems to be maloformed.

Comment: Hi @macpak Did you have a try with task AzureKeyVault? how did it go?

Comment: I've changed an approach a little bit - instead of keeping a certificate as certificate in kv, I put it as a secret and now everything works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I am no Kubernetes expert, but here goes :)

The error indicates the MAC (Message Authentication Code) is wrong, which means you might not have the correct password for the PFX file. What I would do is take the PFX file and see if you can decrypt it with openssl:

openssl pkcs12 -in certfile.pfx -out certfile.pem

you will be prompted for a pwd, if it doesn't work, then you do have the wrong pwd.

I hope that helps. let me know if you need more help.

Comment: as I mentioned, the pwd seems to be correct, because when I upload a certificate (as a k8s secret) manually (without changing the password secret), everything works

Comment: no, but it's very weird. I upload a cert to Azure KeyVault (I need to provide a password). Then I download the same cert, try openssl, provide exactly the same pwd, and get: Mac verify error: invalid password?

Comment: When you download certificates from Azure KeyVault, they have a blank password.